# CSS - Any way to limit element from being cut-off

Tags: html, css

I have an error box that pops up for validation errors from forms. The number of errors within the box varies so the height of the box is not static. Because the box is aligned against the bottom of the screen absolutely, if the errors exceed a certain amount (which is albeit a good bit) the box is cut off on the bottom of the screen. Does css have any kind of property that causes height of the container to adjust vertically up instead of down or possibly limit the box to never go outside of the screen?

Comment: position: absolute; bottom: 0; should be making it stick to the bottom of the screen and grow upwards.  It seems like you're suggesting after a certain point, it gets too big and begins growing down?  If that's the case, are you sure you're not aligning it to the top?  I made a pretty big box, bottom absolute aligned, and it simply kept growing upwards even after it was too tall for the screen, but remained bottom aligned and was never cut off at the bottom of the screen.  Some sample html/css could be helpful unless someone else has already answered your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set max-height and set **EDIT**: overflow:*auto* as @ckuetbach answered.

Answer (score 2):

There's no really easy way to do that without javascript, but another alternative would be using the CSS overflow property and a scroll bar.

Here's a good article about that:

> http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

And if you're interested in the javascript, I would take a look at jQuery's height():

> http://api.jquery.com/height/